# Change the master template for calendar pages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar

Within SharePoint 2013, I don't want my Calendar view at

```
http://xxx/Lists/Calendar/calendar.aspx
```

To use the same master page as the SharePoint administrative master template.

I want to give that calendar page either its own master page or its own page layout. What is the best way from the browser to do that?

Answer (score 0):

From the browser, I don't think you can, but you can open this page in SharePoint Designer and make it point to your master page.

**Updated Answer**

Open SharePoint Designer on the site that contains your calendar. From the left pane click `Lists and Libraries` then choose your Calendar. Then under `Views` double click beside the link `Calendar` to open the page itself. Once you open `Calendar.aspx` Click `Advanced Mode` from the ribbon. Then search for the attribute: `MasterPageFile` and change its value to `"~masterurl/custom.master"`

Comment: OK how do we do that from SharePoint desinger?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @blachawk , please see my updated answer.